# How to add spaces between numbers and non numbers except for dates?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, split, nlp

I'm working on a NLP feature that processes sentences with units. (e.g. "Show me my projects above 300g started after the 10/10/2012 in a 30km radius")

I need to pre-process the string to change "300g" to "300 g" and the "30km" to "30 km" so that it can be treated as two separated values/words.

My code is in Node.js.

My first solution was:

```
    str = "Show me my projects above 300g started after the 10/10/2012 in a 30km radius";
    result = str.match(/(\d+|[^\d]+)/g).join(' ');
    result => "Show me my projects above  300 g started after the  10 / 10 / 2012 in a  30 km radius"
```

My problem is that the dates are split as well and I need them to remain whole to be detected as dates.

I don't want to match the format date with spaces and remove the spaces afterwards because it could change the user input (the user might input a math equation that could be wrongly treated as a date if we remove the spaces. e.g. "3 * 10 - 10 - 2016 + 42" would become "3 * 10-10-2016 + 42")

It's a bit far fetched but It seems a lot safer to not add spaces instead of removing the spaces I wrongly added.

What I am tring to do instead is split my string into an array with dates separated form the rest :

```
["Show me my projects above 300g started after the ", "10/10/2012", "in a 30km radius"]
```

and then I would do the str.match(/(\d+|[^\d]+)/g).join(' '); on the elements that are not dates.
Unfortunatly I can't find a way to split my string that way. I've try the following regex :

```
str = "Show me my projects above 300g started after the 10/10/2012";
result = str.match(/(\d{1,2}[/-]\d{1,2}[/-]\d{2,4})|([^\d{1,2}[/-]\d{1,2}[/-]\d{2,4}])/g);
```

But the syntax is not right (as seen here : https://regexr.com/3s9m8)
I don't know how to match the part that aren't dates as the [^...] doesn't work with complex statement.

Is there a way to do that regex, or do I need to find a different way to do that ?

Thanks in advance, 
Thibaud.

Comment: Could the numbers have decimal or thousands separators?

Comment: Yes, but I want them to remain as is (300,000,000.00m would just split the m from the number).
It was not working with my first solution and I didnt' even notice as I didn't try that. 
Thanks for raising that issue. 

The solution from Nick to only split numbers from letters should work with commas and dots (they won't get split).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple options for solving this. Either you could give a list of suffixes to split off or you could just make sure it splits letters and that is it.

`/(\d+)(g|kg|m|km)/g` would be the start of the suffix list

`/(\d+)([A-Z])/ig` would be based on splitting letters

I would then suggest doing your preprocessing with a simple replace function.

```js
const string = "Show me my projects above 300g started after the 10/10/2012 in a 30km radius";
console.log(string.replace(/(\d+)([A-Z])/ig, "$1 $2"));
```

You may also use a positive lookahead to simplify that replace function a bit.

```js
const string = "Show me my projects above 300g started after the 10/10/2012 in a 30km radius";
console.log(string.replace(/(\d+)(?=[A-Z])/ig, "$1 "));
```

Comment: The first suggestion isn't great as my dictionary is quite big and might evolve with time.

But the second one will do the trick ! 
It's so simple I'm just astonished I just spent an afternoon fixing that. 

Many thanks !